# Error When Stubbing Intent with Espresso

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I have two applications that interact with each other through intents. I would like to verify that let's say *App A* correctly calls the `startActivity` for *App B* without actually launching *App B*. I have tried various combinations of `intending` and Espresso still launches *App B* through the intent instead of just stubbing it out. This causes the remaining tests to fail as the UI is blocked by *App B*. Any ideas?

```
@RunWith( AndroidJUnit4.class )
@LargeTest
public class MyActivityUiIntentsTest
{

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> activityRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<>( MyActivity.class, true, false );

    @Test
    public void shouldStartOtherActivityWhenButtonClicked ()
    {
        Intents.init();
        intending( toPackage( "my.package" ) )
            .respondWith( new ActivityResult( Activity.RESULT_OK, null ) );

        activityRule.launchActivity( new Intent() );

        onView( withId( R.id.viewId ) ).perform( click() );
        intended( hasComponent( hasShortClassName( "the.other.class.name" ) ) );

        Intents.release();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:** Code for the `onClick`:

```
@OnClick( R.id.viewId )
public void startOtherActivity ()
{
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClassName( "my.package", "the.other.class.name" );
   startActivity( intent );
   finish();
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for Intent creation in the onClick? And have you logged package names on the intents? I.e your intending is not catching the correct intent

Comment: Added the `onClick` sample code.

Comment: What device/emu API version are you running on?

Comment: that is strange. Also I thought `IntentsTestRule` dealt with `init` and `release` for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `intending...` code below launchActivity and remove `.init()` because the `IntentsTestRule` will call init for you after the activity is launched

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible solutions is to have indirection for intent dispatching.

For example we have `IntentDispatcher` which we replace with test implementation in functional ui tests via trick with [custom instrumentation test runner](http://artemzin.com/blog/how-to-mock-dependencies-in-unit-integration-and-functional-tests-dagger-robolectric-instrumentation/).

Real implementation of `IntentDispatcher` just calls `context.startActivity()` while in tests we open special activity that displays all content of the `Intent` so we're able to verify that it was `Intent` that we wanted to process with Espresso matchers.

Also we wrote bunch of rules to handle things like opening camera app and mocking the result or just mocking regular `startActivity()` calls.

Comment: Hey Artem and Annyce.. Can you recommend any materials on mocking intents and extras? Any better recommendation in 2018 with newest testing libraries? Thanks